# Print values based on conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath

I have the following xml

```
<isoColumns TYPE="time" ISOFID="175" LABEL="Time" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="0" ISOCID="251330" LINEFEED="X"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  COLNAME="DATE_OF_LASTCHANGE" LABEL="Date of last change" />

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  LABEL="Date for SP"  ISOCID="251325"  TXTHEAD="Baseline data"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  LABEL="Date of report" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251331" />

<isoColumns TYPE="time" ISOFID="175" NORDERBY="11" NULLABLE="Y"   LABEL="Time"  ISOCID="251179" />
```

I want to print the `LABEL` attribute from each row, but if the current row also has an attribute called `TXTHEAD`, I want to print that too (plus a newline). In the above XML, only the 3rd column has the attribute `TXTHEAD`

So what it should print is (notice the new line after the TXTHEAD attribute value) :

```
Time
Date of last change
Date for SP
Baseline data   (This is the TXTHEAD attribute)

Date of report
Time
```

Here is my attempt. Obviously my approach is wrong. I want to express like:

"Print the label attribute value of the current row/isoColumn, BUT if it has a TXTHEAD attribute, print that too, and make a linebreak"

```
var parser = new xmlDom.DOMParser();
var serializer = new xmlDom.XMLSerializer();

var root = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
var obj = xpath.select("//isoForms[@ISOFID='" + isoFID + "']", root);

for (let n of obj) {

       let labs = xpath.select("isoColumns[@CATEGORY[.!=0 and .!=8 and .!=10] and (not(@INPDF) or INPDF='Y')]/@LABEL", n);  
        for(let lCount=0; lCount<labs.length; lCount++){
            let tHead = xpath.select("../../*[@TXTHEAD]/@TXTHEAD", labs[lCount]);
            if(tHead.length > 0) {
                //console.log("THVal: "+tHead[0].value);
                let bLine = xpath.select("../../@TXTHEAD", tHead[lCount]);
```

With the solutions that I have tried, I run into problems with this piece of code:

```
let tHead = xpath.select("../../*[@TXTHEAD]/@TXTHEAD", labs[lCount]);
```

`tHead` will be a list smaller that `labs`, and so I get an error. Therfore I am thinking that if I can print the `TXTHEAD` attribute in the same run as the `LABEL` attribute, then I wouldn't have to store `TXTHEAD` in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to xpath 3.1, you can try this:

```
let th = xpath.select("//isoColumns ", root);
for (let t of th) { 
    label = xpath.select('./@LABEL',t);
    thead = xpath.select('./@TXTHEAD',t);
    out = (thead.length>0) ? label[0].nodeValue+"\r\n"+thead[0].nodeValue+"\r\n" : label[0].nodeValue;
    console.log(out)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider moving to XPath 3.1 as supported by Saxon-JS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js) and then the code is

```
require('saxon-js');

let data = `<root>
<isoColumns TYPE="time" ISOFID="175" LABEL="Time" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="0" ISOCID="251330" LINEFEED="X"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  COLNAME="DATE_OF_LASTCHANGE" LABEL="Date of last change" />

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  LABEL="Date for SP"  ISOCID="251325"  TXTHEAD="Baseline data"/>

<isoColumns TYPE="date" ISOFID="175"  LABEL="Date of report" INFORM="Y" INQUERY="N" CATEGORY="2" ISOCID="251331" />

<isoColumns TYPE="time" ISOFID="175" NORDERBY="11" NULLABLE="Y"   LABEL="Time"  ISOCID="251179" />
</root>`;

console.log(SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml($data)//isoColumns!(@LABEL, if (@TXTHEAD) then @TXTHEAD || codepoints-to-string(10) else ()) => string-join(codepoints-to-string(10))`, null, { params : { data: data }}));
```